# Will allocate array make memory more managable than declaring allocatable?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocation

The problem came from extending a medium size (~8000 lines) Fortran 90 code. I have not managed to isolate the problem into an executable unit.

The thing is, there is an array declared as

```
    integer,     allocatable  :: somename(:,:)
```

Compiling it with ifort leads to

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

When I add

```
        if (.not. allocated(somename))   allocate(somename(somedim1,somedim2))
```

The code will run normally.

My question is, does allocate variable with explicit dimension somehow improve the memory management and avoid segmentation fault?

P.S. I asked at [software engineer stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405376/will-allocate-array-make-memory-more-managable-than-declaring-allocatable), but I am not sure if here is more appropriate.

Comment: The array must be allocated before it is used.  Your fix suggests that the array was not allocated before use.   It is hard to know without seeing the full program.  Compiling with debugging options might give you a more informative error message than segmentation fault.